# Rails state machine dependent on associated data?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I have a model for orders, which have many items:

```
class Order < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :items
end

class Item < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :order
end
```

Orders will have a status, and individual items will have a status, as they get shipped and paid for separately. Once all the items for an order have been shipped (their end state), the order should transition to its end state (order complete).

I've read up on state machines for individual models. Would they be applicable here? Can I make a state machine for items check that all their sibling items are shipped, and if so, update the order state? Would/could this be a callback, or better an Observer?

I'm working in Rails 3.1 if that makes a difference.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I do use [state_machine](https://github.com/pluginaweek/state_machine) gem for a very similar process where one project has many documents.

I've project's states depending on it's documents' states.

When one `document` reaches it's final state, the `state_machine` triggers a method on the associated `project`. This method is responsible to trigger or not the `state` change.